# Save to Google Drive via API

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Using javascript or/and PHP and connecting to the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/) (SDK), I want to allow a user to **upload a file to their own Google Drive account**. Example button:

```
<div class="save-to-google-drive"
   data-url="//example.com/path/to/filename.docx"
   data-filename="filename.docx"
   data-title="Title of file">
      Upload to 
</div>
```

When a user clicks this button, it should upload to their Google Drive account.

The aim is to mimic the behavior of the [Save to Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive) button.

Comment: I will bounty this question with 400 points when it is eligible.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look into the [Google php client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) while it would be possible to do this with javascript really personally i think it would be easier with php.

```
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'photo.jpg'));
$content = file_get_contents('files/photo.jpg');
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'fields' => 'id'));
printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

Code ripped from [doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads)

You are going to need to be authenticated i have some sample code for that [here](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3)

**Oauth2CallBack.php** [link](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/oauth2callback.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';
// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();
// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = buildClient();
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client = buildClient();
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
    // Add access token and refresh token to seession.
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
    //Redirect back to main script
    $redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

**Oauth2Authentication.php** [link](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    $client = getOauth2Client();
    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
return $client;
}
/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed.
 * Example:  array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function buildClient(){

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
    $client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());  
    return $client;
}
/**
 * Builds the redirect uri.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app#choosingredirecturi
 * Hostname and current server path are needed to redirect to oauth2callback.php
 * @return A redirect uri.
 */
function getRedirectUri(){
    //Building Redirect URI
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                    //returns the current URL
    if(strrpos($url, '?') > 0)
        $url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '?') );  // Removing any parameters.
    $folder = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/') );   // Removeing current file.
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $folder. '/oauth2callback.php';
}
/**
 * Authenticating to Google using Oauth2
 * Documentation:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Returns a Google client with refresh token and access tokens set. 
 *  If not authencated then we will redirect to request authencation.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {

        $client = buildClient();

        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }

        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 

            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';
$_SESSION['mainScript'] = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);   // Oauth2callback.php will return here.
$client = getGoogleClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
```

Note: service will then be used to call the api with.

Comment: There you go check the git project if you want updated versions and the readme explains how to use it.   I recomed using composer to grab the library.

Comment: The first time you run it it should pop up asking for authentication and return to you.   The read me for this can be found here https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3 it explains how to set up your developer console and set up the scripts properly

Comment: I see the problem. Your code above is incorrect, for example, instead of `oauth2callback.php` you have `Oauth2CallBack.php` and you are missing the service files etc. I have uploaded all the github files and I believe I have authorized it. Can you kindly update your answer with the relevant code to *upload* to drive?

Comment: @DaImTo Wow, been scrolling through your git and lovely work! I am also very interested in seeing working code to upload file to Google Drive. Maybe you can demonstrate with some relevant code how user can click a button and it triggers `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile()`... do you have a custom function in your files? This is a great answer nonetheless and look forward to seeing it bountied. My concerns however is that it is currently incomplete when considering the aim of the question at hand.

Comment: I think that you have miss understood the point of stack we are not a codeing service.   I suggest you give this a try.  What I have given you is more than enough for you to get it working.  if you have any issues please let me know.